# 3D points on a surface PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot some points on a surface. The result I want to get is (the plot at the right):
[image]

I tried the following code (x_k contains the coordinates of the points I want to plot):

```
f = lambda x : x[0]**2+x[1]**3+3*x[0]*x[1]
x_axis = [x_k[i][0] for i in range(0, len(x_k))]
y_axis = [x_k[i][1] for i in range(0, len(x_k))]
z_axis = [f(x_k[i]) for i in range(0, len(x_k))]

x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 30)
y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 30)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(np.array([X, Y]))

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,alpha=0.8,cmap='viridis',edgecolor='white',linewidth=0.3)
ax.scatter(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis, zdir='z',marker='.', s=10, c='black', depthshade=False)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And I get this:
[image]

See that points are transparent because of the surface...

[image]

I want them to be black, so as to see them better. How could I do that? Thank you!

Comment: This is a known problem, which can currently not be fixed, see [issue #7684](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7684/). Or more generally [My 3D plot doesn't look right at certain viewing angles](https://matplotlib.org/api/toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles).But there [might be workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929216/plotting-single-3d-point-on-top-of-plot-surface-in-python-matplotlib).